# Outlook rule for emails with recipients only in the BCC field

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter, rules, bcc

An outlook rule for incoming emails with the condition: "If the email recipients are not shown in the **To** nor in the **CC** field" Or "If the only field with recipients is the BCC field."

Comment: Are you looking to set this rule for messages that you are sending?

Comment: Sorry - incoming. Edited accordingly.
Why the -1? That bad of a question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about an automatic rule for incoming messages, but you can filter your inbox to show only messages with blank "To" and "Cc" fields.

To set the custom filter go to the **View** tab, click **View Settings**, click the **Filter...** button, and then the **Advanced** tab in the dialogue box shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

To pick out the messages you receive by way of BCC, click the **Field** drop-down menu, go to **Frequently-used fields**, and select **To**. Set the condition to **is empty**, and click **Add to List**. Do the same for the **CC** field and click **OK**.

Comment: Don't see the rule window as you do (I'm using Outlook 2010). Can't find any "Advanced" tab or menu anywhere. 
Just a page with a checklist of conditions, where the only 2 conditions that mention the "To" are: "where my name is in the To or Cc box" and "where my name is in the Cc box". (Can't attach a screenshot in a comment, apparently)

Comment: I accessed these advanced variables in the Filter options. I thought that the same dialogue would be available when setting up a rule, but that might not actually be the case. I'll update my response.

Answer (score 0):

[Message header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Ll2.png)
[Undisclosed recipients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNfuK.png)

The message header can be viewed in 365 web version, when the TO: field is left blank, it shows: "To: Undisclosed recipients:;"

Comment: Now, we need to figure out how to apply a rule to emails when the sender and recipient are EQUAL, like To: me, From: me.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show how to create such a rule.

Comment: Interesting find! I actually stopped using the outlook app (it was getting buggy for me), and am purely on online version now. I see what you mean, but not sure how to make a rule out of it - the online version gives very limited options for rules. But if anyone can confirm that a rule can be made in the app with this, I'll mark this as the answer. :)